# Optional Partials in DustJS

Tags: node.js, templates, express, dust.js

Is it possible to have optional partials in Dust? Let's say I define a layout like this:

```
<div>
    {>"{module}"/>
</div>
```

I have been defining the module in Express's `res.locals` object. However, what if I forgot to define a module, or I actually want a default module for use when I do not define one? Worse, what if I did define one but it's the incorrect module, meaning there's no template file in the view folder with the name of that module? I don't want the user to see the ugly error message, which seems to be something like:

```
Error: ENOENT, open 'view_path\{module}.dust'
```

where `{module}` is the name of the module, or an empty string if I did not specify a `res.locals.module`. Should I resort to try-catch blocks (not even sure how to do them in `dust`), or is there a method for making templates optional, rather than required? **NOTE**: The template would be optional, but the `module` variable would (usually) still be a string. It seems that `dust` sections are optional, meaning if the exact key is not available, the section is simply not included. For example, say I have the context `{friends: [{name: "Harry"}, {name: "Ron"}, {name: "Hermione"}]}`. If I define the section:

```
{#friends}
    {name} is {age} years old.
{/friends}
```

it will output

```
Harry is  years old.
Ron is  years old.
Hermione is  years old.
```

Notice there are 2 spaces between `is` and `years` in each case, where the `age` would be if we defined any ages. If this functionality is included, how is it that neither the original creators of `dust` nor `LinkedIn` thought to not require partials? **How do I specify optional partials in `dust`?**

Comment: The double spaces thing should be no big deal because the browser will only render a single space.  I'm sure you could mod the handlebars code to add whatever handling you want for a missing partial.

Comment: I do not intend to put the code with the sections into my application, so I didn't test it to make sure it had 2 spaces. I kind of just assumed. Regardless, I do not care at all about the 2 spaces so it is, indeed, "no big deal"; that was just an example.

Comment: What's with the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a conditional like so,

```
<div>
  {?module}
    {>"{module}"/>
  {:else}
    {>"{YourDefaultPartial}"}
  {/module}
</div>
```

This will work when `{module}` is either `undefined` or an `empty string` or a `falsey` value.

But, in case its a `string` pointing to a `partial` that does not exist, it'll throw an error. Hope this helps.

Comment: This does not help. My `module` variable will usually be defined, as a string, but I don't want the page to have to be there.